# Why is setTimeout not executing at the expected time?

Tags: node.js, settimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('hari');
    process.exit()
}, 300);

for(i=0;i<3000000;i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Please explain why setTimeout is not finished in 300 ms here. setTimeout is executing only after the `for` loop completes; why?

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know, Node.js is using the [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) (JavaScript) engine which is single threaded. The core of I/O execution is around an event-loop; when you block the event loop it also blocks execution of other events.

Basically, the `for` loop is executed before, and it starts blocking the event loop. The `setTimeout` does not guarantee that your code gets executed *exactly* after 300 ms, but more like `>= 300 ms`. To get a better understanding of event loop [read this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

Answer (score -2):

Basically, your code runs in a single thread. `setTimeout` has lower priority than your standard code, so it will execute first and then (because the thread will be finished) it will execute your function from `setTimeout`.

`setTimeout(milliseconds)` runs a function no faster than in the specified number of milliseconds.